# jQuery getScript – Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I dynamically load a JavaScript file using jQuery's `$.getScript()` method. The FireFox console always tells me that there is a "syntax error" in the first line. However, the script proceeds to work just fine.
The first line is nothing but

```
function SomeFunc (param) {
```

as it is the start of a class. Adding a dummy class to the beginning of the file, like this:

```
function Dummy () {
    return false;
}
```

... it shows the syntax error for the first line (`function Dummy () {`). Does anyone know what's causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a BOM or something there? Isn't Firebug more specific about the syntax error?

Comment: Have you checked it on other browsers as well?

Comment: @DavidHoerster: Adding a `;` causes the error to go away in exchange for a "not well-formed" error.

Comment: @Bergi I will check for that. Edit: Nope, no BOM as far as I can tell.

Comment: I've seen that help before - oh well.

Comment: Edit: Sorry, my mistake. Firebug does show an error too. It doesn't say anything more helpful, though. Seems like jQuery is causing it somehow?

Comment: If I understand this right, jQuery is trying to load it as a XML file. This confuses me, though, since `$.getScript` should be loading it as a script?